# exchange web services: uploading attachment to web server

Tags: exchange-server, image-uploading, exchangewebservices, email-attachments

I've been researching this for a while, but I can't find how to tie things together. The scenario is as follows: in order for mobile users to upload images to a website, I am configuring a mailbox on an Exchange 2010 server. The idea is that users mail an image to this mailbox, which is monitored.

As soon as a message is received, the monitoring process should read the e-mail for three things: sender (which is linked to users on the website), subject (which will be added to the image as a description), and attachment (the actual image). The monitoring process should then create a HTTP POST (multipart/form-data) with the three relevant fields from the e-mail and send this to a webserver with a formhandler that expects those three fields and acts accordingly.

Here's what I know so far:

- Exchange EWS can give me access to messages and their attachments. I will probably be using ASP.NET for this. I can gain access to the EWS managed services. I have found sample code to work with individual messages.
- Exchange EWS offers triggers to act when new mail arrives, but I haven't found exactly how to implement them.
- I can probably find a way to prepare the form data, sending it to the webserver shouldn't be a problem using winHTTPRequest.

My question is: how to tie all this together. Ideally I write a script (ASP.NET) that reads the message, isolates the attachment, Base64 encodes it, then POSTs it to the webserver. I then write a "rule" that triggers the script whenever a new message arrives on the monitored mailbox.

I would greatly appreciate your help/feedback.

Comment: [Here are many useful examples for your use-cases](http://www.independentsoft.de/exchangewebservices/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Your link points to a library for EWS. I was already at the point where I can interface with EWS; I could not discover the "trigger" function I am looking for on the page you linked.